# Efficiently counting relationship with criteria

Tags: ios, macos, sqlite, core-data, count

Consider two Core Data entities: **Document** and **Category**. A document can have many `categories`, and a category can have many `documents` (the inverse relationship). Also, Document has a boolean attribute `opened`, which is `YES` if the document has been opened.

Using Core Data, what is the most efficient way of counting the opened documents of a given category?

Or is Core Data smart enough to use inverse relationships to optimise this fetch request?

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Document"];
fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate 
    predicateWithFormat:@"opened == YES AND ANY categories.name == %@", 
    categoryName];
NSError *error = nil;
NSUInteger count = [context countForFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
```

**Edit**:

Apparently it is. The generated SQL for the above fetch:

```
SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT t0.Z_PK) 
FROM ZDOCUMENT t0 
JOIN Z_3CATEGORIES t1 ON t0.Z_PK = t1.Z_3DOCUMENTS 
JOIN ZCATEGORY t2 ON t1.Z_4CATEGORIES = t2.Z_PK 
WHERE ( t0.ZCD_OPENED = ? AND  t2.ZNAME = ?)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is excellent. I think it is the most efficient way to do this fetch in Core Data.

I guess `@"opened == YES"` will work,
but `@"opened == 1"` or `@"opened == OK %@", @YES` will work for certain.

(And, if you like brevity, you can replace `==` with `=`.)

Comment: Thanks Mundi. Do you know if this behaviour is documented somewhere? After all, what Core Data is doing behind the scenes is not obvious.

Comment: Turns out that fetching the category and iterating over its notes is way faster than the single fetch in my question. If I can I'll isolate the code and post the Instruments comparison.

Comment: I don't believe that iterating through the results is faster than `countForFetchRequest`. Maybe you are iterating through some list of category names and calling the fetch repeatedly - that could be expensive. But that would be another question.

Comment: Yes, I'm doing that exactly. That said, it might be that the JOIN used by `countForFetchRequest` is not leveraging the index I have on Category.name, whereas fetching the category by name is. Not sure how to profile that.

Comment: I just validated the fetch you request in my answer. Of course, there are a different ways to get to the desired data. Iteration is not necessarily inefficient, indeed, the Core Data Programming Guide says so explicitly (section on fetching). I still think you should re-accept my answer.